# Upgrade to Ubuntu 14.04 causes Qt compile/link issue

Tags: qt

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 14.04 and now I'm having a problems compiling a Qt program that was formerly built using Qt4. (Qt5.2.1 was installed as part of this recent upgrade.) I'm not using the IDE but have been using qmake to build my project. The complier first complains that it can't find the QT file  (or any of the other qt includes). If I add the following line to my .pro file, it finds the includes:

```
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/include/qt5/QtWidgets
```

but then the linker complains:

> g++ -L/home/marieh/LaCrosseWs/sharedlibs -L/home/marieh/wthrTrax/libs
>   -Wl,-O1 -o ../../../../../apps/qtSampler obj/qtSamplerApp.o   -llc23xxAdapters -llc23xxIO -llitecmisc -lwxm -lQt5Network -L/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu -lQt5Gui -lQt5Core -lGL -lpthread  /usr/bin/ld: obj/qtSamplerApp.o: undefined reference to symbol
>   '_ZN12QApplicationD1Ev' //usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtGui.so.4: error
>   adding symbols: DSO missing from command line collect2: error: ld
>   returned 1 exit status make: *** [../../../../../apps/qtSampler] Error
>   1

It seems to be missing some library files or something.

Comment: Don't add that; add `QT += widgets`.

Comment: Are you sure you want to port the Qt4  app to Qt5? It's not a lot of work, but still there almost certainly are things you need to fix to make it build and work on Qt5. You can always still use Qt4, it is fully supported by Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I don't have a line QT += widgets, just the INCLUDEPATH shown in my original post. Is that what you meant? Without that, the compiler complains it can't find <QApplication>. I didn't intend to upgrade to Qt5 but when I upgraded to Ubuntu 14.04, Qt5 was installed with it. I thought the upgrade would be "mostly" backward compatible. -Silly me.

Comment: OK thanks. I didn't understand peppe's reply. I've added QT += widgets to my .pro file and now everything seems to work fine.